# The default expression

Tags: c#, generics

In C# specification is said, at first:

> If the type in a default-value-expression evaluates at run-time to a
>   reference type, the result is null converted to that type. If the type
>   in a default-value-expression evaluates at run-time to a value type,
>   the result is the value- type’s default value (§4.1.2).

So it seems like the default expression is evaluated at run-time... but
after is said:

> A default-value-expression is a constant expression (§7.19) if the
>   type is a reference type or a type parameter  that is known to be a
>   reference type (§10.1.5). In addition, a default-value-expression is a
>   constant expression if  the type is one of the following value types:
>   sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, char,  float,
>   double, decimal, bool, or any enumeration type.

so how can be `default` a constant expression, thus evaluated a compile-time, if only a runtime a type is checked?

For example, if I write something like:

```
J k = default(J);
```

where `J` is a type parameter, only at runtime, when we provide the argument type, we can know if `J` is a reference type or a value type.
So what does happen at compile-time?

Comment: How can we know `J` only at runtime and have `default(J)` in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're simply reading the specification wrong (emphasis mine):

> - A default-value-expression is a constant expression (§7.19) **if** the type is a reference type or a type parameter that is known to be a
>     reference type

This means, if (and only if) the type or the type parameter is known to be a reference type (meaning, it has the `where T : class` constraint or `default(SomeClass)` is used), then the expression is constant. Continuing:

> - In addition, a default-value-expression is a constant expression **if** the type is one of the following value types: sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, char, float, double, decimal,
>     bool, or any enumeration type

Meaning, that for some reason you're using `default(sbyte)` or `default(short)`.

For example, give then following code:

```
void Main()
{
    var x = default(byte);
    var y = default(M);
}

public struct M { }
```

The emitted IL will be:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // x
IL_0003:  ldloca.s    01 // y
IL_0005:  initobj     UserQuery.M
IL_000B:  ret
```

Where for `byte` the compiler could emit 0, it has to call `initobj` for our `M` struct.

Comment: So we can deduce that default evaluate at compile time only if the compiler "KNOWS" that type is a reference type or a value type (byte, int, etc.). Else default evaluate a runtime and this is the case where generic are defined without constraints.

Answer (score 0):

It is evaluated at compile time because so is `J`, you don't provide the argument type at runtime but at compile time so if you have a class `foo<J>` that contains a method bar with the code you mentioned when you do

```
foo<int> myfoo =new foo<int>(); // this is also evaluated at compile time
myfoo.bar(); // the compiler invokes the bar method of the foo<int> type and thus returns default(int)
```

Comment: However what you're saying is in contrast with: """the type in a default-value-expression evaluates at run-time to a reference type"""

Comment: No it doesn't, it simply specifies what default will return (the implementation of default), not what type it returns, the wording is ambigous and it's even less clear since you removed the if but it simply states how default will behave when faced with the different types, not what type it will return (it basically simple explains that for value type you get the default value type and for reference types you get null, this has Nothing to do with determining the type you get, only the value of that type you get)

Comment: Hmm actually sounds like i'm off topic from the question, will delete my answer, edit: actually won't remove my answer althought it doesn't answer the question because it does answer the ", only at runtime, when we provide the argument type, we can know if J is a reference type or a value type" assumption that was made by the OP, not sure if i should delete it or rewrite it as a comment

Comment: I am , i had understood the question as "how can it know the type of J since we don't know it at compile time" instead of "how can it be a constant value", i definately don't answer that part by stating that the foo<int> will have default(int), i do answer what J will be but not wether default will do the work at runtime or compile time (nor do i know it)

Answer (score 0):

> If the type in a default-value-expression evaluates at run-time to a reference type

If the type evaluates at compile-time to definitely reference type or definitely not, then what it will evaluate to at run-time can be determined at compile-time.

This is true of `default(string)` and `default(int)` but not of `default(T)` within a generic method (or method of a generic class) with a type parameter `T` (unless constrained in a way that means it can only be one of the other).

As such, the reference-type or non-reference-type quality can only be deduced at run-time.

Strictly though, it can in fact be deduced at jit-time, and this is indeed done, including code that is known to be dead by this logic not being compiled, so in:

```
if (default(T) == null)
{
   // code for reference-type or Nullable<> types of T
}
else
{
  // code for non-nullable value types of T
}
```

Only the branch used will be compiled to machine code, and the comparison itself skipped in either case.